# Calculating the time complexity of a recursive Grid Traversal function

Tags: python, recursion, math, time-complexity

I have the following recursive function that takes 2 indices `i` and `j` and a flag `up` indicating the traversing direction; up or down a grid.

```
def helper(self, i, j, up):
        self.visited[i][j] = True
        if up == 0:
            if i == len(self.grid) - 1: return True
            nei = [
                [i, max(0, j - 1)],
                [i, min(len(self.grid[0]) - 1, j + 1)],
                [min(len(self.grid) - 1, i + 1), j],
                [min(len(self.grid) - 1, i + 1), min(len(self.grid[0]) - 1, j + 1)],
                [min(len(self.grid) - 1, i + 1), max(0, j - 1)],
            ]
        else:
            if i == 0: return True
            nei = [
                [i, max(0, j - 1)],
                [i, min(len(self.grid[0]) - 1, j + 1)],
                [max(0, i - 1), j],
                [max(0, i - 1), min(len(self.grid[0]) - 1, j + 1)],
                [max(0, i - 1), max(0, j - 1)],
            ]

        for k in nei:
            if not self.visited[k[0]][k[1]] and self.grid[k[0]][k[1]]:
                if self.helper(k[0], k[1], up):
                    return True
        return False
```

In short words, it returns `true` if there is a path from the input indices to the top/bottom of a square 2d matrix of size `nxn`, and `false` if not. However, the problem comes when trying to calculate its time complexity since the number of recursive calls depends on the neighbor's values and `visited` state.

The `grid` representing the 2D matrix is a binary matrix, and we can suppose that the probability of a neighbor to be traversable is the same for all of them and equal to `P`, which actually is a function `P(x)=1-(1 - 1/n^2)^x` with `x` being a temporal variable independent of the traversal iterations of `helper` function, so we can simplify it to a fixed value `P`. Additionally, the probability of a neighbor being already visited by `helper` cannot be assumed to be fixed like P since it depends on the specific iteration and path followed by the function.

The problem comes when trying to formalize the time complexity recurrence relation (in the situation of `up` flag being 1, since the opposite has an equivalent complexity):

`T(i, j) = P (T(i, j-1) + T(i, j+1) + T(i-1, j) + T(i-1, j-1) + T(i-1, j+1)) + O(1)`

1- The number of recursive calls is variable and dependant of `P` and visited probability. Thus, is it correct to multiply each recursive term by `P` or `P+V` to represent this probability?

2- Is there an easy way to calculate the probability for a neighbor to be visited?

3- If the above expression is correct with `P` or `P+V` term, how can it be solved without having to compute an upper and lower bound? In other words, how accurately can this recurrence relation be solved?